# Is there any way to set Priority for any test case like we have in TestNG during execution in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, selenium, testing, automation, cypress

I have a suite name "Customer Profile" in the Customer.spec.js file, under that there are many 'it' blocks like below. here I want to run the 'Delete profile' Test case at the end of the suite as it is dependent on creating customers and sharing the same user_id to update and manage customers.
#Note: I want this to be at the Test case level.

describe('Customer profile',function(){

it('Create Customer', function(){
});

it('Edit Customer Customer', function(){
});

it('Manage Customer', function(){
});

it('Delete Customer', function(){
});

})

Comment: It should already run in the order they appear in the file. Are you seeing something different?

Comment: No, didn't check I just thought to confirm before. I thought it run alphabetically order. @Fody

Comment: You may want to separate your tests a creating a new customer, working with an existing customer, and deleting a customer.

Comment: @jjhelguero No, I don't want to separate my tests. I want to work with the new user_id created in first test(Create customer) in all other below test case.

Comment: Your tests should not be dependent on each other. You can end up with false negatives and it will be hard to debug.

Comment: @jjhelguero So you are saying every time need to create a new customer before running the other 3 test cases mentioned above is good practice? In current design I am using the 'UserId' created in createcustomer test in all other test cases. And there are more other test case which is taking parameter as 'UserId'. How do you suggest this scenario.

Comment: If you need to create a new user for each test, it would be better to do it via API rather than on the UI. Then you'll create the UserID inside a `beforeEach()` block.